# Cross compilation cgo project from Mac x86 for M1

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to cross compile go app which is written in C, Objective-C, and Go.
It works fine on Mac x86, and I am trying to use the cross-compile it for M1.

So simply ran

```
GOARCH=arm64 /usr/bin/go build -o "~/Example/project/obj/mac-arm64/dummy" -gcflags "-N -l" -ldflags "-w" -race dummy
```

```
CC version:
joshiga@joshiga-a01 bin % /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/

CXX version:
joshiga@joshiga-a01 bin % /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/

$ go version
go version go1.16.9 darwin/amd64
$ go env
GOARCH=arm64
GOOS=darwin
'GOROOT': '/Users/joshiga/ws/dev/main/bora/build/package/COMPONENTS/cayman_go/sb-51450161/macosx-catalina/apple_mac64', 'GODEBUG': 'cgocheck=2', 'GOARCH': 'amd64', 'CGO_ENABLED': '1', ''GO111MODULE': 'off'
```

I was expecting it to successfully crosscompile and create a binary for ARM. Please
note for x86 Mac it works fine.

```
joshiga@joshiga-a01 bin % uname -a
Darwin joshiga-a01.vmware.com 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Tue Oct 12 18:33:42 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

But the got the below error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"___tsan_acquire", referenced from:
_runtime.raceacquireg in go.o
_runtime.raceacquirectx in go.o
"___tsan_finalizer_goroutine", referenced from:
_runtime.runfinq in go.o
"___tsan_fini", referenced from:
_runtime.racefini in go.o
"___tsan_free", referenced from:
_runtime.(*mspan).sweep in go.o
"___tsan_func_enter", referenced from:
_racefuncenter in go.o
"___tsan_func_exit", referenced from:
_runtime.racefuncexit in go.o
"___tsan_go_atomic32_compare_exchange", referenced from:
_sync/atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32 in go.o
"___tsan_go_atomic32_fetch_add", referenced from:
_sync/atomic.AddInt32 in go.o
"___tsan_go_atomic32_load", referenced from:
_sync/atomic.LoadInt32 in go.o
"___tsan_go_atomic32_store", referenced from:
_sync/atomic.StoreInt32 in go.o
"___tsan_go_atomic64_compare_exchange", referenced from:
_sync/atomic.CompareAndSwapInt64 in go.o
"___tsan_go_atomic64_fetch_add", referenced from:
_sync/atomic.AddInt64 in go.o
"___tsan_go_atomic64_load", referenced from:
_sync/atomic.LoadInt64 in go.o
"___tsan_go_atomic64_store", referenced from:
_sync/atomic.StoreInt64 in go.o
"___tsan_go_end", referenced from:
_runtime.goexit1 in go.o
_runtime.(*p).destroy in go.o
"___tsan_go_ignore_sync_begin", referenced from:
_runtime.RaceDisable in go.o
_racecallatomic in go.o
"___tsan_go_ignore_sync_end", referenced from:
_runtime.RaceEnable in go.o
_racecallatomic in go.o
"___tsan_go_start", referenced from:
_runtime.racegostart in go.o
"___tsan_init", referenced from:
_runtime.raceinit in go.o
"___tsan_malloc", referenced from:
_runtime.mallocgc in go.o
_runtime.gfget in go.o
_runtime.stackalloc in go.o
"___tsan_map_shadow", referenced from:
_runtime.raceinit in go.o
_runtime.racemapshadow in go.o
"___tsan_proc_create", referenced from:
_runtime.(*p).init in go.o
"___tsan_proc_destroy", referenced from:
_runtime.(*p).destroy in go.o
"___tsan_read", referenced from:
_runtime.raceread in go.o
"___tsan_read_pc", referenced from:
_runtime.racereadpc in go.o
"___tsan_read_range", referenced from:
_runtime.racereadrange in go.o
_runtime.racereadrangepc1 in go.o
"___tsan_release", referenced from:
_runtime.racereleaseg in go.o
"___tsan_release_acquire", referenced from:
_runtime.racereleaseacquireg in go.o
"___tsan_release_merge", referenced from:
_runtime.racereleasemergeg in go.o
"___tsan_write", referenced from:
_runtime.racewrite in go.o
"___tsan_write_pc", referenced from:
_runtime.racewritepc in go.o
"___tsan_write_range", referenced from:
_runtime.racewriterange in go.o
_runtime.racewriterangepc1 in go.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas or suggestions what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: It might be related to "-race" argument. It is stated that "Supported only on linux/amd64, freebsd/amd64, darwin/amd64, windows/amd64,
 linux/ppc64le and linux/arm64 (only for 48-bit VMA)." in https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go

Comment: I am thinking the same. Based on names on  *race*, thanks for pointing out that this flag is not yet supported on ARM. I will try removing the flag and see how it goes.

Comment: Its working fine now after removing race flag for Darwin ARM. Thanks for the help!